How do I filter coverage for only the relevant files/dependencies (including 3rd party dependencies)?
I want to have a coverage report for dependencies that maybe 3rd party.
It seems like that I need to point --source to the 3rd party dependencies directory (under venv site-packages) or else it will only show dependencies in the project src directory.
However, using --source=src,3rdpartydirectory, seems to scrape coverage for every file in the src and the 3rd party directory, instead of only the ones that should be invoked by my dummy test.
I see on the report a lot of files with 0% coverage because no lines are executed.
The command I'm using is:
coverage run --
source=/usr/local/home/.../Workspace/project,/usr/local/home/../.virtualenvs/project/lib64/python3.11/site-packages dummy_test.py --debug=trace

and then:
coverage html

dummy_test.py just import numpy, and print. numpy is the 3rd party dependency in the site-packages directory.
I was hoping to see only coverage for dummy_test.py + its direct/indirect dependencies (eg, numpy). What's the recommended way to go about it?
More details can be found in https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/1759.
